# Scrolling issue on Cordova for android 5.0+

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

When testing on an android device using android 5.0 and above I am able to scroll way passed the end of the page as shown in the following:

[image]

This only happens on the android side and only on android versions 5.0+, I am not seeing this issue on any of my IOS devices or any android device with 4.x and below.

I am using the following versions of tools

- Cordova 6.4.0
- JQuery 1.7.2
- JQuery mobile 1.1.0

Is this caused by the versions of the libraries i'm using or is it a known issue with cordova on android 5.0+?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your code or screenshot?

Comment: Sorry I didn't notice the link to my screenshot was broken, Is there any specific part of the code you need to see?